# Getting "NoSuchMethodError" error when trying to set up restassured framework using cucumber bdd

Tags: java, cucumber, rest-assured

I am trying to setup API automation framework with rest-assured library and cucumber BDD. Previously I had setup but never encountered this error. I got this error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.restassured.common.mapper.resolver.ObjectMapperResolver.isJakartaEEInClassPath()'
```

Below is my code

```
public class ReqResApi implements AutoCloseable {

    private String baseUri;
    private String basePath;
    private static RequestSpecification requestSpecification;

    public ReqResApi(String baseUri, String basePath) {
        this.baseUri = baseUri;
        this.basePath = basePath;
    }

    public RequestSpecification getRequestSpecification() {
        return requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
                .setBaseUri(baseUri)
                .setBasePath(basePath)
                .build();

    }
}
```

And this is my step definition code

```
public class AssignmentDefinition {

    private HashMap<String, String> map;
    private RequestSpecification requestSpecification;
    private String baseUri;
    private Response response;
    private ReqResApi reqResApi;
    private String endpoint;

    public AssignmentDefinition() {
        this.baseUri = ReqResConstants.propertiesConfig.baseUri();
        this.endpoint = ReqResConstants.propertiesConfig.endpoint();
        reqResApi = new ReqResApi(this.baseUri, endpoint);
    }

    @Given("user should be able to list users")
    public void userShouldBeAbleToListUsers() {
        response = given()
                .spec(reqResApi.getRequestSpecification())
                .when().get().then().statusCode(200).extract().response();

        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    }
}
```

This is the first time I have received an error. Can anyone provide some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is to make sure that you are using same version for below ,if you are using rest-assured of version `4.2.0` then you should keep all the related version for json-path ,rest-assured-common and  xml-path

```
rest-assured-4.2.0
json-path-4.2.0
xml-path-4.2.0
rest-assured-common- 4.2.0
```

if it doesn't work Try to exclude the conflicting dependency by adding the exclusion tag in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If this doesn't work then you need to run command `mvn dependency:tree`
It might be related to conflicting dependencies or different versions of dependencies, you can use the mvn dependency:tree command to generate a tree-like structure of all the dependencies required to build the project. This structure includes information about the group ID, artifact ID, and version of each dependency, as well as their transitive dependencies. By examining the output of this command, you can identify any conflicts or duplication of dependencies that might be causing the issue.

You can also see read detailed info [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/maven-dependency-tree-resolving-conflicts)

Updated - Give this version a try

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not working. I tried all of your suggested solutions

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I used 4.X

Comment: can you once try with above latest version